# tabSlideOut - trigger click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using this tabSlideOut plugin which can be seen [here](http://spyrestudios.com/wp-content/themes/spyrestudios/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js). It creates a slider which is triggered by a tab handle.

It works as intended, but I would like it to slide out when you hover the tab and clicks the slider - not just the handle.

In the plugin there's a function called slideIn(), but when I try to call it I get an error - probably because it's out of scope.

This is the code I'm trying to add:

```
$('#contactContainer').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            //slideIn()
        }
});
```

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/iyEYUCe/1/).
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code, which seems to work:

```
$('#contactContainer').click(function () {
     if (!$(this).hasClass("open") && !$(this).is(":animated")) {
         $("#contactTab").click();
     }
});
```

The `:animated` part did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic a `click` on the handle, in your click event. Like this:

```
$('#contactContainer').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $("#contactTab").click();
        }
});
```

I think that's what you're looking for (?)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iyEYUCe/6/edit)

Comment: Yes, that's something like that I'm looking for. Except that I would like to be able to close it again by clicking the content area. See what happens if we add:

       if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $("#contactTab").click();
        } else {
        $("#contactTab").click();
        }

:-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all its jsBin not a fiddle ;)

why dont you just set the action on hover like so:

```
action: 'hover',
```

I dont see why you should click then? as it gets out before you can even click on it?